# Ansible playbook run for the servers in the list

Tags: ansible

quick question for Ansible Guru's. I want to run an ansible playbook for a specific set of boxes that I copied to a list.txt disregarding the inventory and the target block in ansible playbook:

```
---
- name: Ansible Runbook v.1.0
  hosts: test1
  gather_facts: yes
#  serial: "10%"
```

When I am running the following command I am getting no hosts matched:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --tags "simplejson" -vvv -i /x/home/list.txt

PLAY [Ansible Runbook v.1.0] **************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

$cat list.txt
hostname2b
```

Any ideas for a workaround ?

Comment: Can you please paste some of the text file to show us what you're trying to get Ansible to parse?

Answer (score 1):

The reason of no host matching is that host `test1`, which is hardcoded in playbook, is not present in the inventory file that you specified from command line. The problem is `ansible-playbook` command does not accept any `hosts` parameter. So there is no direct way of getting around the hardcoded hosts `test1`.

However, there is a workaround for this as explained [here](https://github.com/k4ml/importerror/blob/master/posts/ansible-playbook-specify-hosts-on-the-command-line.md). You can use a variable for `hosts` and specify `all` from command line for that variable. Something like this:

```
---
- name: Ansible Runbook v.1.0
  hosts: "{{ host_param }}"
  gather_facts: yes
```

Then pass that variable with `extra-vars`:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -i /x/home/list.txt --extra-vars="host_param=all" --tags "simplejson" -vvv
```

Comment: hmmm. I am still getting the same message. ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --extra-vars="hosts=hostname2" --tags "simplejson" -vvv
PLAY [Ansible Runbook v.1.0] **************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

Comment: @Zerg12 do you really have a host named `hostname2`? Your sample output of the files is showing `hostname2b`.

Comment: Does it make any difference ? it could be anything server2.box.com. I think I have figured it out it should point to a host group tag in the inventory file [ group1]